# How to build a simple standalone expert system with Drools or CLIPS or others in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, drools, clips

I am new with Drools and CLIPS. I want to build a simple diabetes diagnosis expert system that run on android. I am now using Android Studio as my development tools and I am finding the ways to integrate either Drools or CLIPS to build the project. I have searched for weeks but there is no much information is talking about run Drools or CLIPS on Android Studio. Can anyone give some hints to me or give me the links? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you at least tried reading the official documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html/ch14.html ??

Answer (score 1):

This link has an example CLIPS expert system integrated with Android: https://github.com/gomezgoiri/CLIPS4Android